# Does the phase of a weighted series of complex terms $\exp(i k_n x)$ wind?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

**Assumptions and definition of the problem:**

I consider the complex function
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^M a_n \exp(-i k_n x),
$$
where $M>2$ is a finite integer, $x$ is a real-valued number, $k_n$ is a set of monotonically increasing frequencies, $k_{n+1}>k_n$, that are incommensurate with each other, and with $k_0=0$, and $a_n>0$ is a set of real-valued positive weights, with normalization
$$
\sum_{n=0}^M a_n = 1,
$$
and with the largest weight being $a_0<1/2$ ($a_n$ are not necessarily monotonically decreasing).

**Numerical evidence:**

Studying the function $f(x)$ in the complex plane, a host of numerical examples show that the unwrapped phase diverges to $-\infty$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$. Note that for all numerical studies I used commensurate frequencies $k_n$, yielding necessarily a periodic function $f(x)$. The figure below shows an example in the case of a period of 30 and with $a_0$ chosen just barely smaller than 1/2, where the phase diverges to $-\infty$ (you find [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGmIz.jpg) an animation). In this  example, $|f(x)|\neq 0$ for all real-valued $x$.

[image: Phase behavior as a function of x]

**Conjecture:**

I am looking for a proof that the unwrapped phase does diverge to $-\infty$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$. In other words, I would like to prove that the function $f(x)$ winds an infinite number of times around the origin anti-clockwise. Note that whenever $f(x)$ crosses a zero, the phase is assumed to increase by $\pi$, by definition.

**Observations and remarks:**

- The unwrapped phase is simply obtained by continusouly tracking the phase evolution as a function $x$ through the different Riemann surfaces, with the only exception when a zero is crossed. In such a case, the phase is discontinuously increased by $\pi$.
- It is important that $a_0<1/2$. On the contrary, if we have $a_0>1/2$, the normalization condition on $a_n$ requires that no winding occurs. In fact, the weights $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ can be continuously transformed to $(1,0,0,\ldots)$, which corresponds to the trivial function $f(x)=1$, without that $f(x)$ ever crosses the origin.
- It is important that $k_n$ are mutually incommensurate. Otherwise, we can find counterexamples for which no winding occurs. An example is provided by $k_n = n$ and weights distributed according to a Poissonian distribution,

$$a_n=\exp(-\lambda)\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}.$$

- I presume that the same conjecture can be stated equivalently as
  $$
  \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \Re\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^x \frac{1}{f(x)} \frac{\mathrm{d} 
  f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\rightarrow -\infty.
  $$
  However, to determine whether the equivalence is indeed correct, one should carefully consider the case when $f(x)$ crosses a zero for some value of $x$. In this case, I expect the imaginary part of the integral to diverge. For this reason, I considered in the expression only the real part of the integral.

**Additional remarks**

I am interested in this problem for my research work in physics, because it is linked to the behavior observed in some experiments, where we probe the quantum wave function of an atom in a trap potential.

Comment: Possibly related: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/67299/algorithm-to-count-zeros-outside-unit-circle-for-fir-filter